# Eclipse can`t find my photo for button

Tags: java, eclipse, button, jbutton

I`ve started learning JButton options and my eclipse can't find photos that I have saved. And yes, I've saved it to truly the right folder, format is also the right one (png), but I can't find it looking through eclipse and also when I'm running program, my stop faces errors too.
Please share via me how I could fix it, brothers!!

Comment: Sorry brothers, can`t upload photo yet...

Comment: what do you mean "can't find it looking through eclipse"? do you mean you don't see them in the project explorer, or that your code can't find them?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iV-v_m0z0w#t=240

look, the guy from tutorial sees those photos on the left, and in my eclipse there are no photos shown, although I`ve saved them into my source file with the right format. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: how did you add them to the project? Through eclipse?

Comment: Did you try refreshing your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of eclipse explains it quite clearly how to import resource into your project. Here is the [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-55.htm). (I extract the content just below)

```
**Importing resources from the file system**
You can use the Import Wizard to  command link import resources from the local file system into an existing project.

1. From the main menu bar, select  command link File > Import.... The Import wizard opens.
2. Select General > File System and click Next.
3. Click the Browse button on the next page of the wizard to select the directories from which you would like to add the resources.
4. In the import selection panes, use the following methods to select exactly the resources you want to add:
    4.1 Expand the hierarchies in the left pane and select or clear the checkboxes that represent the folders in the selected directory. Then in the right pane, select or clear checkboxes for individual files.
    4.2 Click Filter Types to filter the current selection for files of a specific type.
    4.3 Click Select All to select all resources in the directory, then go through and deselect the ones that you do not want to add.
    4.4 Click Deselect All to deselect all resources in the directory, then go through and choose individual resources to add.
5. Specify the Workbench project or folder that will be the import destination.
6. When you have finished specifying your import options, click Finish.
Tip: You can also import folders and files by dragging them from the file system and dropping them into one of the navigation views, or by copying and pasting.
```

Make sure you follow their instructions to import your picture.